# Ubuntu EFI booting fails after Mac OS X booting

Tags: dual-boot, macbook-pro, macosx, grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu on a Macbook pro (early 2011), from Ubuntu live on USB.

After the install, Ubuntu boots and reboots automatically after restart.

Mac OS El Capitan also boots after pressing the alt key at startup and choosing the volume where it is installed.

However, after having booted Mac OS,  Ubuntu fails to reboot (unless installing again from USB).

How to make Ubuntu reboot after Mac OS X?

I have tried rEFInd but it does not help (it just makes the case more confuse).

I think removing Grub could help.

This is the output of `ls -lR /boot/efi`:

```
efi/EFI:
total 2
drwx------ 4 root root 512 ago 11  2019 APPLE
drwx------ 2 root root 512 mai  8 14:35 BOOT
drwx------ 2 root root 512 mai  8 14:39 tools
drwx------ 2 root root 512 mai  8 14:35 ubuntu

efi/EFI/APPLE:
total 1
drwx------ 2 root root 512 out 21  2019 CACHES
drwx------ 2 root root 512 ago 11  2019 EXTENSIONS

efi/EFI/APPLE/CACHES:
total 0

efi/EFI/APPLE/EXTENSIONS:
total 15361
-rwx------ 1 root root 15729264 mai  8 18:19 Firmware.scap

efi/EFI/BOOT:
total 3729
-rwx------ 1 root root 1334816 mai  8 21:48 BOOTX64.EFI
-rwx------ 1 root root 1213032 mai  8 21:48 fbx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1269496 mai  8 21:48 mmx64.efi

efi/EFI/tools:
total 31
-rwx------ 1 root root 31688 mai  8 20:32 gptsync_x64.efi

efi/EFI/ubuntu:
total 4183
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 mai  8 21:48 BOOTX64.CSV
-rwx------ 1 root root     126 mai  8 21:48 grub.cfg
-rwx------ 1 root root 1677176 mai  8 21:48 grubx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1269496 mai  8 21:48 mmx64.efi
-rwx------ 1 root root 1334816 mai  8 21:48 shimx64.efi
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution.

I found these threads relevant:

[Dual-Booting OS X or macOS with Linux without rEFInd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind)

[Dual-Booting with El Capitan without using rEFInd, how should the bootloader be installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784236/dual-booting-with-el-capitan-without-using-refind-how-should-the-bootloader-be?rq=1)

Actually, I only needed the first one.  In particular, I did this:

```
cp /Volumes/EFI/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /Volumes/EFI/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
```

Yet it didn't work so as suggested I read Adam Williamson's [UEFI boot: how does that actually work, then?](https://www.happyassassin.net/posts/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

Apart from "quite frankly, screw Macs" (maybe) I also found

> The UEFI boot manager is a firmware policy engine that can be configured by modifying architecturally defined global NVRAM variables.

So I tried to reset the NVRAM and the miracle occurred: Ubuntu boots directly.

2021 May 5, I come back on this because I found the cause of the problem: using an external Full HD 1020 line monitor with Mac OS X El Capitan, this higher resolution is written somehow in the NVRAM and not only spoils the display of GRUB and Ubuntu but also cause kernel panic.  The problem can be avoided by disconnecting the external monitor before Mac OS X shutdown.